# Building Android app for website

Tags: android, build, web

I have a website. I want to develop an android app for it and have a custom output.What's the best way to get that? I can get the XML of the pages, but how to put it in the labels and text boxes that I made in my app? Or is it better if I connect it to the SQL? But it's going to require re-programing all the work for mobile .

I would be thankful for any ideas on how to get my website into an android app.

Comment: If you don't want to create a "real" app because it is really time consuming. You can create a mobile website (just the CSS maybe ?) and then create an android application with just a WebView that loads your mobile website.

Answer (score 4):

First of all Android app could be come in two flavours

1. A Native Android Application - This kind of application is where you write all the code in Java, design the (Native) UI components of android and also write the code to handle the business logic or expose your web app's API as a Webs Service and use API calls to your server to do most of the heavy lifting.

   - Advantage : Since you are writing Native Application code you will access to direct Hardware,services etc.. which could allow you to leverage some new break through in technology like Augmented Reality, GPS etc ...
   - Disadvantage : Not really a disadvantage but there is a learning curve involved for Android and also the maintenance that accompanies, when your include new features into your Web app you would also need to do that in your Android.
2. A HTML 5 rendered on the Web view built into a Native app.You can do this using some cool libraries like [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

   - Advantage : With the minimal code you can also have an IPhone/Blackberry version of your app,because you will not need to write application/logic code for your app to work.
   - Disadvantage : I should give you a heads up that you that UI rendered with this kind of Web view/HTML is kind of soggy(the one that does not kind of transition smooth kind).
3. Throw in some [Responsive Design](http://mashable.com/2012/12/11/responsive-web-design/) into the front-end of your Web-app with HTML 5 and JavaScript. This one requires the least amount of work as you will only have to write a separate front-end for your Mobile devices or even tackle that with Responsive Design.

   - Advantage : Basic HTML 5 and some mid level JavaScript can get the Job done.
   - Advantage : You don't need to maintain different versions of your Application, just your front-end.
   - Disadvantage : User experience is the main thing Responsive Design, not just about how the Web app scales to based on device screen size, but also how the UX is consistent and Intuitive.